# Optimized ReaderWriterLock Read Access

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, readerwriterlockslim

So it's my understanding that on a ReaderWriterLock (or ReaderWriterLockSlim more specifically), both the read and write need acquire a mutex to take the lock. I'd like to optimize the read access of the lock, such that if there are no writes pending, no lock need be acquired. (And I'm willing to sacrifice the performance of writes, add some constraints to the reads, make the first read slow and second fast, etc.. if necessary, as long as the vast majority of the reads are as fast as possible.)

So, how would one do this, or even better, is there a framework or "standard" implementation one could point me to? (Or if I've misunderstood and it's supported already, great!)

So for my piece:
It would seem that if one were to have a counter for the number of readers/writers (protected by Interlocked.Increment), that would be enough for the reader to check if the writer count was non-zero, and only acquire the lock then. (And increment within the lock if acquired.)

Writers would always increment, acquire the lock, spin till the reader count went to 0 (willing to assume readers always finish quickly, or even bypass the reader count entirely in an optimistic scenario), and finally decrement.  (It'd be nice to throw in some form priority too when we do block, or potentially clear all pending readers/writers in one pass since I'm only protecting one value, but I'll forgo that for now..)

So.. anyone seen anything similar or have a suggestion? If there's nothing out there after a bit, I'd be happy to throw together an initial implementation and talk more concretely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've described is, at a basic level, already how the reader/writer locks work. They don't need to take a mutex out as the reader/writer lock controls access by using an internal count of readers and writers (and, indeed, a mutex would imply that readers would block each other, whereas in fact multiple concurrent readers are allowed -- that's the whole point of the lock type!).

So yes, there is a framework/standard implementation for this: `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. I really doubt you'll be able to write a reader/writer lock with better performance than this. In any case -- are you sure that this lock is the root of your performance problems?

Comment: Thanks Greg, you're absolutely right. I pulled out reflector and it uses Interlocked.CompareExchange to check before acquiring the lock. Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

I am afraid you are wrong, since ReaderWriterLockSlim is based on spin locking, not on mutexes (you can see this in Reflector).